# Last loop in CodeIgniter foreach

Tags: php

I'm trying to catch the last loop in my CodeIgniter for-loop. I'm trying to generate a < hr /> under every news item but the last one. This is my code:

```
<table class="news">
<?php foreach($news as $news_item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="headline"><?php echo $news_item['title']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text"><?php echo $news_item['text']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><hr /></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: and wht is your question? is it not working or else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уou can try something like this:

```
<?php for($i = 0, $lastIDX = count($news)-1; $i<=$lastIDX; $i++): ?>
    <!-- html code ... $news_item is $news[$i] now -->
    <? if ($i !== $lastIDX) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><hr /></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

But it would be better to use CSS :last-child selector.

Comment: How's it done with the CSS selector then? :-) Adding class="hr" on every HR <td> with 
.news .hr:last-child {
    display: none;
} as the CSS doesnt work out

Comment: forget the hr and use border-bottom:solid 1px #000; use padding to add some distance

Answer (score 0):

Get the last key of the array beforehand and compare it the current one while looping:

```
$keys = array_keys($news);
$last_key = end($keys);
foreach ($news as $news_key => $news_item) {
    if ($news_key == $last_key) {
        // at the last item
    } else {
        // not at the last item
    }
}
```

Also you could count the elements in your array beforehand, and have a counter inside the loop that increments on every round, so you can tell if you are at the end or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one as a solution:

```
$last = end($news);
<table class="news">
<?php foreach($news as $news_item): ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="headline"><?php echo $news_item['title']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text"><?php echo $news_item['text']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?=(($last == $news_item)?"":"<hr />")?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Where the $last is the last array of your array XD.